# Can't delete parent without a child in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have two objects **User** and **Workorder**. One user can have multiple work orders. The problem is when I delete user it also deletes assigned work orders to that user. I have tried to set my work orders foreign keys to NULL before deleting the user but it still deletes all the associated work orders with that user. I'd like to delete user without deleting the work order assigned to user. What am I missing or doing wrong?

Here's is my User class:

```
   @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="user", orphanRemoval=true)
   private Set<WorkOrder> workOrder;
```

WorkOrder class:

```
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="user_id", nullable = true)
    private User user;
```

UserDAOImpl class:

```
    @Override
    public void deleteUser(int theId) {
        // get the current hibernate session

        Session currentSession = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

        // delete object with primary key

        User user = currentSession.get(User.class, theId);  
        Set workorders = user.getWorkOrder();


        Iterator<WorkOrder> work = workorders.iterator();
        while (work.hasNext()){

            WorkOrder workorder = work.next();
            workorder.setUser(null); 
            }   

        currentSession.remove(user);
    }
```

Comment: copy workOrder to new tables then delete user? Like make a copy of workOrder (save it to a new Table), then delete the user. When u delete the user, his/her workOrder will also be deleted. But you saved workOrder to a new table

Comment: It's possible but there should be easy way without creating a new Table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove that 'orphanRemoval=true' and check there's no 'cascade' on Workorder.user (if the relation is bidirectional)

Comment: Removing it did help. Now it sets foreign keys to NULL and delete users. Thank you!